# Cron email-deleter

Tags: python

I made this small program which takes some inputs (emails) and after looking if they exist it looks for the respective id and delete it.  It works (I use it with crontab) but seems redundant.  I had several problems with split and decode function, mainly because decode gives me lists of strings spaced by a tab.  I would like to optimize the code and get rid of all these `for` loops, because the code seems long and sloppy.  Any tips?

```
bastards = [
"team@mail.kamernet.nl",
"supportdesk@kamernet.nl",
"noreply@pararius.nl",
]

with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='imap.gmail.com',port=993) as imap:
    imap.login(email,password)
    imap.select('INBOX',readonly=False)
    listy = []
    for bastard in bastards:
        resp_code, respy = imap.search(None, f'FROM {bastard}')
        respy = respy[0].decode().split()
        listy.append(respy)
    listy = [x for x in listy if x]
    for i in listy:
        for j in i:
            imap.store(j,'+FLAGS','\\Deleted')
            print('email_deleted')
    imap.expunge()
    imap.close()
    imap.logout()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listy` comprehension could be refactored into a generator:

```py
def search_emails(imap, senders):
    for sender in senders:
        typ, data = imap.search(None, f'FROM {sender}')
        msg_nums = data[0].decode().split()
        
        # check for content here
        if msg_nums:
            yield msg_nums


with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='imap.gmail.com', port=993) as imap:
    imap.login(email, password)
    imap.select('INBOX', readonly=False)

    # also, visually breaking up the program with newlines
    # makes it more readable
    for email in search_emails(imap, senders):
        for j in email:
            imap.store(j, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            print('email_deleted')
```

This evaluates lazily, so you don't have to keep all of your emails in a list that you filter out later. It filters them as you iterate over the generator.

## `for j in email`

This inner loop doesn't need to be there, per the docs on [`IMAP4.store`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.store), it takes a set of messages, not one at a time:

```py
    ~snip~
    for emails in search_emails(imap, senders):
        imap.store(emails, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
        print('emails_deleted')
```

The official docs also don't have the `decode` section when parsing the output from `IMAP4.search`:

```py
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')

for num in data[0].split(): # <------ Here
   M.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
```

I haven't used this library, so I won't speculate on why your snippet is different, but just a note.

## Variable Names

Things like `for i in iterable` and `for j in iterable` usually imply indices. I'd change the names here to more accurately represent what they are, it makes the code more readable

## Function Params

Add spaces in between your function parameters:

```py
# go from this
imap.login(email,password)

# to this
imap.login(email, password)
```

## Passwords

You can use the `getpass` library for a masked password prompt:

```py
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass()
```

I'm not sure how you're currently implementing storing the password, since you haven't included it.

Comment: incredible explanation